# Building a SQL query for this

Tags: mysql

I am trying to do the following but I dont have enough experience with MySQL. Would it be possible for someone to tell me what the query for this will be.

I have a databse with 2 tables

- Brief
- Info

`Brief` and `Info` have various fields but I am interested in only **`ID`** field.

This is what I am trying to do.

> I want to go through all the **IDs** from
>   **Brief** and cross reference them  with
>   all the **IDs** that exists in **Info** and
>   only get the ones that **exist in Info**
>   but **dont exist in Brief**

Thanks

Comment: It would be helpful with a little more detail on what your tables look like.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT i.ID
FROM Info i 
  LEFT JOIN Brief b USING(ID)
WHERE b.ID IS NULL
```

Alternatively:

```
SELECT i.ID
FROM Info i
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM Brief b
  WHERE b.ID = i.ID
)
```

See these 2 links for performance comparisons:

- [NOT IN vs. NOT EXISTS vs. LEFT JOIN / IS NULL: MySQL](http://explainextended.com/2009/09/18/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-mysql/)
- [LEFT JOIN / IS NULL vs. NOT IN vs. NOT EXISTS: nullable columns](http://explainextended.com/2010/05/27/left-join-is-null-vs-not-in-vs-not-exists-nullable-columns/)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT ID FROM INFO 
   WHERE ID NOT IN 
   (SELECT ID FROM BRIEF);
```

Answer (score 1):

SELECT * from info i LEFT JOIN brief b ON b.id=i.id WHERE b.id IS NULL